# How to dynamically add stops in a Gradient

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the following gradient:

```
    Item {
        id: base
        width: 200
        height: 100
        start: Qt.point(0,0)
        end: Qt.point(width, 0)
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "white"}
            GradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "black" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "white"}
        }
```

The stops property of [Gradient](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-lineargradient.html#gradient-prop) doesn't have any member functions to append new stops and neither does [LinearGradient](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-lineargradient.html#gradient-prop).

How could I add stops to dynamically change the gradient?

The alternative is to create a new LinearGradient each time it is to be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Gradient` is defined as a [`list`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-list.html) property which, as stated in the linked documentation, cannot be modified by directly appending/removing elements

The only way to append new stops to the `Gradient` is by reassigning the `stops` property `list`. Here is a sample code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 100

    Rectangle {
        id: base
        anchors.fill: parent
        gradient: Gradient {
            id:gradient

            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "white"}
            GradientStop { position: 0.1; color: "black" }
            GradientStop { position: 0.3; color: "white"}
        }

        Component
        {
            id:stopComponent
            GradientStop {}
        }

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            // Type 1: Aassign a all new stop list
            var s1 = stopComponent.createObject(base, {"position":0.2,"color":"red"});
            var s2 = stopComponent.createObject(base, {"position":0.4,"color":"yellow"});
            var s3 = stopComponent.createObject(base, {"position":0.6,"color":"blue"});
            gradient.stops = [s1,s2,s3];

            // Type 2:Append to the original stop list
            var newStops = [];
            for (var idx = 0; idx < gradient.stops.length;idx++)
            {
                newStops.push(gradient.stops[idx]);
            }
            newStops.push(s3);
            gradient.stops = newStops;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked a treat. There is an added caveat that once the component is created, completed and on-screen, any changes to the gradient thereafter must be followed with a call to `base.update()`. Is that possibly a bug?

Comment: I didn't call base.update(), what is your Qt version?